# Global keyboard shortcuts for Desktop Progressive Web Apps?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, progressive-web-apps, desktop-application

Is it possible to build a desktop progressive web application that can listen for keyboard shortcuts even when the app is not in focus, like a native desktop app?